# How to grep for only one `+`at the beginning of a line?

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep for only one `+`at the beginning of a line as follows,I get the lines which has more than one + like `+++` ,the grep should only show lines with one `+` ,any guidance on how to fix it?

```
$ git diff-tree --word-diff=porcelain -p -r 833d9653863f84fce6d04f62896c781d8b88794a|grep '^+'
+++ b/comvendorfeatureInterface.cpp
+func(function1, function2());variable
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
+++ b/comvendorfeatureInterface.cpp
+func(function1, function2());variable
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
+func(function1, function2());variable
```

Comment: Maybe include the next character (a non-plus) in the match.

Comment: Can there be a line that has a single `+` char as the **only** char on the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe search for `+` followed by not a `+`:

```
grep '^+[^+]' file
```